# Force Cucumber to not call the wrong constructor for DataTable

Tags: cucumber-jvm

What is the easiest way to do this without changing the Data class?

```
Feature: My feature
  Scenario: My Scenario
    Given some data table:
      | a | b    | c    |
      |   | true | true |

public class MySteps {
    @Given("^some data table:$")
public void some_data_table (
    final List<ThirdPartyEntity> rows) throws Throwable {
        for (ThirdPartyEntity row : rows) {
            // I get 6 rows here :(
        }
     }
}

public class ThirdPartyEntity extends ... {
    private String a;
    private boolean b; 
    private boolean c;

    public SpecificBenefitRuleRequest() {
        this("x");
    }

    public SpecificBenefitRuleRequest(String x) {
        super(x); // cucumber calls this, but I don't want it to :(
    }
// getters and setters for a,b,c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way I found was to hide the constructors that I don't want cucumber to call by overriding the entity in my test class:

```
public class MySteps {
    @Given("^some data table:$")
    public void some_data_table (
        final List<ThirdPartyEntityCucumberHatesMe> rows) throws Throwable {
            for (ThirdPartyEntityCucumberHatesMe row : rows) {
                // I get 1 rows here \o/
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ThirdPartyEntityCucumberHatesMe extends ThirdPartyEntity {
        // this was the easiest way to get cucumber to not call the wrong constructor :'(
    }
}
```